# GCP instance does not start service StackDriver Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I have migrated a windows server 2008 r2 to GCP, in the process of putting it into production recreate the disks from snapshot and image in another project where I made sure in its creation that the instance had the default service account with the default permissions among the which is writing to StackDriver Monitoring, even so when installing the agent in the operating system, it does it without any problem, when verifying the service is stopped, when it starts it automatically stops again and registers the following in the event viewer log:
[error metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEpbE.png)

On the other hand, and verified that there is communication with metadata.google.internal and not, for this reason request the client to recreate the registry in the DNS for said resolution:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwC6c.png)

even so, metadata.google.internal still does not respond, despite the fact that the machine does have Internet access open in the firewall and the private access vpc is also enabled.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you having an issue just with Stackdriver Monitoring or is it that the instance cannot communicate with the metadata server at all? Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall the Stackdriver Monitoring agent?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with StackDriver Monitoring, and in the review I noticed that there is no communication with the metadata server, of course if you have tried to reinstall the agent and the guest agent is also installed, but it still does not work.

Comment: I would suggest creating a Public Issue Tracker as this doe not sound like intended behavior. You can submit one using this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187134&template=1162877)

Comment: Thanks, submit suggest in issue tracket.